# JAXB value of a complex type

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, unmarshalling

****Edit - in the end I removed the abstract extension to get this to function,  the answer below from Blaise then works**

Hello.
I have a complex type in my schema:

```
<xs:complexType name="AbstractWorkflow" abstract="true">
    <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:ID" use="required"/>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="ProcessWorkflow" mixed="true">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:extension base="AbstractWorkflow"/>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

The input to be unmarshalled is this

```
<ns1:Workflow stb:id="Workflow" xsi:type="ns1:ProcessWorkflow">workflowHTML.xml</ns1:Workflow>
```

But when I do this I get no option to access the value: workflowHTML.xml from the classes
that have been generated from xjc.  This is the start of the generated AbstractWorkflow class **is there an annotation that I can declare in this class, that extends an abstract class, to specify that it is an element that carries a value itself?**  Shoud it not be declared as a FIELD or?

Edit it is the extending class that I need to implement the reading of a value not the abstract class that I had here originally.

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PUBLIC_MEMBER)
@XmlType(name = "ProcessWorkflow")
public class ProcessWorkflow
    extends AbstractWorkflow
{



}
```

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you are looking for the @XmlValue annotation.

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement
public class Foo {

    @XmlAttribute
    private int id;

    @XmlValue
    private String value;

}
```

The above corresponds to the following XML schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xs:schema version="1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:element name="foo" type="foo"/>

  <xs:complexType name="foo">
    <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:extension base="xs:string">
        <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:int" use="required"/>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

And XML like this:

```
<foo id="123">Some Value</foo>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Blaise.  I have edited my original question.  This will not work in my situation as I already extend an abstract class. In my schema definition ProcessWorkflow is the one that carries a value.  So I already have used the extension tag. Also if I edit the class directly to include @XmlValue I am greeted with @XmlValue is not allowed on a class that derives another class. **So to clarify my question is there a way to add a value to a class that extends/derives another class?**

Comment: @Gurnard - I'm currently fixing a related bug in EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy),https://bugs.eclipse.org/336099.  As long as a parent class does not map anything to an element you should be able to map to value in the child class.  This bug also exists in the JAXB reference implementation.  Once this fix is checked in, you could solve your problem by using MOXy as your JAXB implementation:  http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php

Comment: oh ok.  Does MOXy work ok with the package-info.java replacement of namespace prefixes?  The jdk1.6.0_24 implementation of JAXB does not work with this so I have just changed to using the Sun implementation which works well, it seems, for this namespace issue. Just a bit worried about moving to yet another implementation. :-)

Comment: @Gurnard - MOXy will use the prefixes as specified in the @XmlSchema annotation.  The following article explains how to configure MOXy: http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html

Comment: Thanks for the replies.  In the end I have changed the schema so as not to rely upon extending an abstract class in the first place.  So your original answer now functions perfectly thank you.  Now just to get the xsi:type back into the element, but that is another thing altogether, thanks for your assistance and good luck with MOXy.

Comment: OK I now have the type definition in also.  So I have removed the inheritance and added a value and now added a new attribute for type this `    @XmlAttribute(namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance", required = true)
    protected String type;` with the appropriate getters and setters and it all works, I get my element with a type and a value.